# Android textview swipe with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, textview

I'm new in android and I was wondering if it's possible to swipe (left, right) a textview with effects to change the text of based on a DB or adapter data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement with OnSwipeTouchListener (https://gist.github.com/nesquena/ed58f34791da00da9751)